# Hide sending parameters from url

Tags: java, get, struts-1, url-parameters, struts1

I should use link. And it means that method GET and all parameters I can see in url. How I can hide parametrs from url like that

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/action.do?method=delete&amp;id=0
```

And how after that I can get parametrs in java class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't hide GET parameters from a URL. GET name value pairs have to be part of a request. However one thing you can certainly try is to encrypt your querystring into a string which only your code can decode on your host, for example

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/action.do?method=delete&amp;id=0
```

could be

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/action.do?param=[ENCRYPTED/OBFUSCATED STRING]
```

then your application at the above url can decode that and convert back into name value pairs

Comment: i don't know exactly but exist way using javascript with onsubmit

Comment: With JavaScript you can try alot of things, for example you could write a jquery function on link click that would post data to your link using AJAX post and then redirect to it, Or you can encode the querystring as mentioned above and decode later on your link's landing page

Comment: Thanks for the idea.I used plexux Base64 api to encode it and it worked. However extra java code had to be written. It would have been great if there was a way to send hidden url params.

Answer (score 2):

That's the idea of GET method - to path parameters through URL, probably you should use POST.